# Start a hangout with already set of existing email id(participants)

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

Is it possible to start a hangout with existing list of participant, i mean i want to avoid Add participant box, when i open my hangout app. I have gone through the API documentation, couldn't find an answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

That is not currently possible.